# Where is geonetwork doing the check if a namespace is belonging to a path

Tags: xml, geonetwork, standards, customize-mode, xsl

Inside GeoNetwork, for each standard in config-editor.xml are declared fields with xpaths. Ex. `<field xpath="/gmd:MD_Metadata/gmd:identificationInfo/*/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title"/>`

If I create a record and I declare `<gmd:title>Test</gmd:title>` outside declared xpath it won't be shown. I need to customize, to make GeoNetwork show a namespace when xpath matches with the declared one, but also to show it when xpath does not match with the one declared.